# Does statefulset transfer data if restarted with higher volume?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-pvc

I have a statefulset having `2` replicas and I want to increase the storage in each of the pods from `300GB` to `3TB`. So I edited the statefulset to increase the storage.

But this doesn't get reflected directly. I plan to do a rollout restart using the command of type:

`kubectl rollout restart statefulset my-statefulset`

But I am not sure if this will create Pods with fresh volume or if there is an easy way to ensure that it transfers the old data of `300GB` to the volume of `3TB`.

I am using GKE.

Client Version: v1.16.1

Server Version: v1.14.10-gke.42

Comment: Are you on cloud or onprem k8s ? What version of k8s are you using ?

Comment: cloud, GKE
Client Version: v1.16.1
Server Version: v1.14.10-gke.42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is way expand volumes . Steps in brief

1. Your storage class should have allowVolumeExpansion field to true and provisioner should support it (in case of GKE if your volumes are provisioned with provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd this will work).
2. Edit the storage  in PVC ( remember you can only expand the volume and not shrink it)
3. After you edit it will wait for pod restart for the expansion to take place. Once pod restarts it will expand the volume.

Reference Doc : [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/)